# charging 12v lead acid battery with OEM charger

Tags: batteries, lead-acid

I have an ExpertPower 12V 7 Amp EXP1270 Rechargeable Lead Acid Battery ([link on Amazon here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003S1RQ2S)) and would like to safely charge it. Do you think this charger (Battery Tender 021-0123 -- [link here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000CITK8S)) is an appropriate option? Based on the specs, it seems that they're compatible but since I don't have a background in electronics, I want to make sure I will not have an explosion in my place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That charger should be fine for a 7 Ah battery.

The maximum recommended charge rate for a lead-acid battery is 1/4 of the Ah capacity, which would be 1.75 amps for your battery.  The cvharger you suggest is rated to provide 0.75 Amp, which is well under the maximum for your battery, but sufficient to charge it in a reasonable time - about 10 hours for a full charge.

Comment: To make this a useful answer I think you need to explain how you came to this conclusion. Otherwise the answer has no value to the next person with a similar question.